# White space due to page break (except on the last sheet)

Tags: jasper-reports, page-break

I am creating a jasper report with a page break, which generates a new page when a specific field changes. But i observe a lot of blank space at the bottom of the pages (except the last sheet of the report).

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of the page and change page height so that no white space is under your page break. I am not sure if it will help because your question is not clear enough